# Need it to inherit a number instead of string

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass

```
System.out.println("First Camera: " + camera1.getName()+ " " + camera1.getResolution());
```

This is the println statement that should read:
First Camera: Nikon 800 Resolution

The method getResolution is only giving 0 and not the number i set it to in the child class.

```
public void setResolution()
{
    this.Resolution = 0;
}

public int getResolution()
{
    return Resolution;
}
```

These are the setters and getters.

What needs to be changed for it to update properly?

Comment: your mutator method needs a parameter..., otherwise `Resolution` will always be `0` (if it's `private`). and if you don't mind, could you include all relevant code in the parent and subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setter always sets Resolution to 0. You should have:

```
public void setResolution(int resolution) {
  this.resolution = resolution;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your setResolution method should read:

```
public void setResolution(int res){
    this.Resolution = res;
}
```

Currently your setter is only ever setting the resolution to 0, no matter how it is called.

Comment: if the field is either `public` or `protected`, it could be modified in the subclass without the need for a mutator method. so, i would think more information would be needed in order to correctly answer this question.